# Point to a specific location on the page using JS

Tags: jquery, layout, animation

I am creating a large page with many sections in it, so that the page looks like one huge canvas and users can scroll to different sections of it. Similar to this website: http://www.yourauxiliary.com/
The only difference being that in my website users can also use scroll-bars:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

My problem is that if the user starts scrolling, pressing one of the menu links won't lead to the right location.

Initially I had this code in the JS for each one of the anchor points:

```
$("ul#menu a#link1").click(function(event){
    $('#pane-container').stop().animate({'left':'0px', 'top':'0px'},scrollSpeed);
    event.preventDefault();
}

$("a#link2").click(function(event){
    $('#pane-container').stop().animate({'left':'-1000px', 'top':'0px'},scrollSpeed);
    event.preventDefault();
}

$("a#link3").click(function(event){
    $('#pane-container').stop().animate({'left':'-2000px', 'top':'0px'},scrollSpeed);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

etc. for all the 8 links.

This code works fine if I don't allow scrolling. Since I need the scroll-bars, I added this to each anchor point:

```
$("ul#menu a#link1").click(function(node){
    $('#pane-container').stop().animate({'left':'0px', 'top':'0px'},scrollSpeed);
    event.preventDefault();
    var parent = node.parent;
    var parentCHeight = parent.clientHeight;
    var parentSHeight = parent.scrollHeight;

    if (parentSHeight > parentCHeight) {
        var nodeHeight = node.clientHeight;
        var nodeOffset = node.offsetTop;
        var scrollOffset = nodeOffset + (nodeHeight / 2) - (parentCHeight / 2);
        parent.scrollTop = scrollOffset;
    }

    if (parent.parent) {
        scrollIntoView(parent);
    }
});
```

This works fine for anchor points that are above where the scroll-bar is; however, it doesn't work if the anchor point is below the scroll bar.

Does anyone know how to solve this? How do you get the link to always point to the correct anchor point on the page, regardless of where the scroll is?

Thanks so much!!
Noa

Comment: you should use proper tags for your question. By "pointers" someone means memory pointers, like in C/C++.  
"node.js" is a javascript library for client/server interactions.  
"scrollview" generally refers to a gui element that contains something to scroll. Appropriate tags would be: jquery, layout, animation

Answer (score 1):

### Code

i generally use this snippet:

```
$('a[href^=#]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var hash = $(this).attr('href');
  var that = $(hash)[0];
  var mem = that.id;
  that.id += '-tmp';
  location.hash = hash;
  that.id = mem;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(that).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

automatically applies to all anchor links, scrolls to their referenced position and changes the # mark on the location bar.

### Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/8tuL4

Comment: I tried pasting this snippet at the top of my JS file, but now the menu links don't work at all, they are not even clickable. Am I placing this snippet in the wrong location?

Comment: roman's answer begins by a selector 'a[href^=#]', that is every element a with an href attribute that begins by "#". You used the following selector: ul#menu a which will aim for every a in ul[id="menu"] (links and maybe anchors with the name attribute) but no a element outside of this particular #menu

Comment: @Noa, added an example on jsfiddle

Comment: So how do I write this? Sorry, I'm a real newbie... I just tried removing the ul#menu with roman's code but again the links don't work at all now...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:
The example page is using background position to move the background canvas around. This is fine when there is no scrolling, because the container's 0,0 position is always located at the top left of the window. However, when the user manually scrolls, the 0,0 position of the container is now hidden up and left of the visible part of the browser (i.e. the canvas is no longer adjusted to the 0,0 of the container). Therefore, when the menu is clicked and the background position changes, the user is still viewing a point where the top left of the browser is +x and +y, not 0,0 for the container.

Since I want to allow scrolling, I had to do the following.

1. update the javascript to point to specific x,y scrolling positions on the scrolling container (body) rather than changing the background position. See this website for use of 'scrollLeft' and scrollTop with the animate() function: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/
2. make the body overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%. This put horizontal/vertical scrollbars on the page and made it the same width/height of the browser window.